# Who was the Prophet's first wife?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, wives-of-the-prophet

I have some questions about the first wife of the Prophet.  My questions are:

- What was her name?
- How did the prophet come to know her?
- How old was she?
- Who was her father?
- Who was her mother?

But, if I am only allowed to ask one question at a time, then that single question would be:

Was the first wife of the Prophet a virgin before she got married to the Prophet i.e., was the first wife of the Prophet previously married/divorced?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**What was her name?**

- Khadijah (peace be upon her)

**How did the Prophet come to know her?**

- According to Al-Raheeq al-Makhtum, "the Prophet (peace be upon him) went to Syria as a merchant for Khadijah(pbuh). She was a business-woman of great honor and fortune. She used to employ men to do her business for a certain percentage of profits."
- She knew about his honesty, good manners etc. So she proposed for marriage.

**How old was she?**

- She was 40 years old at the time of marriage and the Prophet was 25 years old.

**Who was her father?**

- Khadija, daughter of Khwailid

**Who was her mother?**

- Fathima bint Zaidah

**Was the first wife of the Prophet previously married/divorced? Was the first wife of the Prophet a virgin before she got married to the Prophet?**

- She was a 2-times widow.

---

**Sources**:

- [Ar-Raheeq Al-Makhtum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar-Raheeq_Al-Makhtum)
- Last two answers from [Wikipedia article on Khadija bint Khuwaylid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khadijah_bint_Khuwaylid)

Comment: your last answer is wrong she was a two times widow even according your sources but three times married!

Comment: @Medi1Saif : Yeah, I am sorry it is my mistake. It was a mis-reading. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit it now.

Answer (score 6):

For Shia view:

```
What was her name?
```

**Khadijah (AS)**

```
How did the Prophet come to know her?
```

The Prophet Mohammad(sawwas) was not hired by Khadijah(as) for her trade. Frankly He was a merchant sharing trading with Khadijah(as).

```
How old was she?
```

She was 25 years old when she got married with Prophet Mohammad(sawwas)

```
Who was her father?
```

Khwailid son of Asad son of Abd Ozza son of **kossay son of Killab**

Note that she was very close to Prophet in ancestry.

**Mohamad** son of AbdoLLAH son of Abd Motaleb son of Hashem son of Abd Monaf son of  **kossay son of Killab**

```
Who was her mother?
```

Fathima bint Zaidah son of Alassam.

```
was the first wife of the prophet previously married/divorced? Was the first wife of the prophet a virgin before she got married to the prophet?
```

Most of sources says NO. She had never got married before the Prophet(sawwas) although there are some historical says about yes she got married. ALLAH knows.

---

**Read this for more information:**

- http://www.al-islam.org/articles/khadijah-daughter-khuwaylid-wife-prophet-muhammad-yasin-t-al-jibouri

Comment: +1 I never knew about this view being Sunni Muslim. That's why we should keep this site up.

Comment: In Shia view she, peace be upon her, was 25 when married the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household? You might have intended to say the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household was 25 years old at his marriage and she was 40?

Answer (score 3):

**The Prophet's first wife (Khadijah)**

What was her name?

> Khadijah, Daughter of Khuwaylid

How old was she?

> She was 40 years old when married prophet Muhammad.

Who was her father?

> Her father was Khuwaylid ibn (son of) Asad ibn Abdul-`Uzza ibn Qusayy
> belonged to the clan of Banu Hashim of the tribe of Banu Asad.

Who was her mother?
>  Khadijah's mother, who died around 575 A.D., was Fatima daughter of Za'ida ibn al-Asam of  Banu `Amir ibn Lu’ayy ibn

> Ghalib

Was she previously married/divorce?

> Some historians believe that she previously had married
> twice.(although some historian believe she hadn’t any husband before
> prophet Mohammad(pbuh)

How did the prophet come to know her?

Read the following text to obtain some information:

> ...Since Khadijah did not travel with her trade caravans, she had always
> had to rely on someone else to act as her agent to trade on her behalf
> and to receive an agreed upon commission in return. In 595 A.D.,
> Khadijah needed an agent to trade in her merchandise going to Syria,
> and it was then that a number of agents whom she knew before and
> trusted, as well as some of her own relatives, particularly Abu Talib,
> suggested to her to employ her distant cousin, Muhammadibn Abdullah
> (ص).  Muhammad (ص) did not have any practical business experience, but
> he had twice accompanied his uncle, Abu Talib, on his trade trips and
> keenly observed how he traded-, bartered, bought and sold and
> conducted business. After all, the people of Quraish were famous for
> their involvement in trade more than in any other profession. It was
> not uncommon to hire an agent who did not have a prior experience; so,
> Khadijah decided to give Muhammad (ص) a chance. He was only 25 years
> old.

> Someday , Khadijah sought the advice of a friend of hers named Nufaysa daughter of Umayyah. The latter offered to approach him on her
> behalf and, if possible, arrange a marriage between them. Nufaysa came
> to Muhammad (ص) and asked him why he had not married yet. "I have no
> means to marry," he answered. "But if you were given the means," she
> said, "and if you were bidden to an alliance where there is beauty,
> wealth, nobility and abundance, would you not then consent?!" "Who is
> she?!" he excitedly inquired. "Khadijah," said Nufaysa. "And how could
> such a marriage be mine?!" he asked. "Leave that to me!" was her
> answer. "For my part," he said, "I am willing." Nufaysa returned with
> these glad tidings to Khadijah who then sent word to Muhammad (ص)
> asking him to come to her. When he came,

She said to him:

> O son of my uncle! I love you for your kinship with me, and for that
> you are ever in the center, not being a partisan among the people for
> this or for that. And I love you for your trustworthiness, and for the
> beauty of your character and the truth of your speech.  Then she
> offered herself in marriage to him, and they agreed that he should
> speak to his uncles and she would speak to her uncle, Amr son of
> Asad, since her father had died. It was Hamzah, despite being
> relatively young, whom the Hashemites delegated to represent them on
> this marriage occasion, since he was most closely related to them
> through the clan of Asad; his sister, Safiyya, had just married
> Khadijah's brother, `Awwam. It was Abu Talib,Prophet Muhammad's uncle, who
> delivered the marriage sermon saying,.. .            For further information
> refer to the following source.

---

**Source:**

- [www.al-islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/articles/khadijah-daughter-khuwaylid-wife-prophet-muhammad-yasin-t-al-jibouri)

Answer (score 2):

Her name was Khadijah, dauther of Khuwaylid.

She was 40 years old when married prophet Muhammad.

Her father was Khuwaylid ibn Asad ibn Abdul-Uzza ibn Qusayy.

Her mother was Fatimah dauther of Zaida ibn al-Asam of Banu Amir ibn Lu'ayy ibn Ghalib.

Was she previously married/divorce?

We have two answers for the question. A kind of historians believe that she had married twice before. The second group of historian belive she had not any husband.

**Source:**

- http://www.al-islam.org/articles/khadijah-dauther-khuwaylid-wife-prophet-muhammad-yasin-t-al-jibouri

Comment: Also not there is some dispute over Khadijah (RA) age. There are some claims who says she was 26 not 40.